# change treeview node color

Tags: delphi, treeview

Is there any way to change the color of the nodes in a TTreeView. I want to color my treeview with a dark color and then I can't see the nodes.

[alt text http://rigo.ro/temp/ChangeTreeViewNodeColor.png](http://rigo.ro/temp/ChangeTreeViewNodeColor.png)

Comment: Please specify which Delphi version you are using. I just checked and in Delphi 7 none of the properties mentioned by "Kornel' are present (apart from Color of course)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not easily evident that you only wanted to change the line color.
Anyway, there's a message for that in the API;

```
uses
  commctrl;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SendMessage(TreeView1.Handle, TVM_SETLINECOLOR, 0, ColorToRGB(clYellow));
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can use OnCustomDrawItem event of TTreeView:

```
procedure TForm1.TreeView1CustomDrawItem(Sender: TCustomTreeView;
  Node: TTreeNode; State: TCustomDrawState; var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
begin
  with Sender as TCustomTreeView do
  begin
    Canvas.Brush.Color := clBlack;
    Canvas.Font.Color := clBlack
  end;
end;
```

Comment: What will this accomplish ? This will draw the items with black foreground and black background. Remus is asking about painting only the tree lines, no ?

Comment: yes, that is true, i want to change only the color of the tree lines